# I must be off if I want to make the next bus. (why 'make' is used?)

Tags: idiomatic-language

> I must be off if I want to make the next bus.

> I must be off if I want to catch the next bus.

> I must be off if I want to take the next bus.

I saw the first sentence using 'make' in a dictionary.

Logically thinking, I consider 'catch' or 'take' is more adequate.

Do natives use 'make' as in the first sentence example? 'make' is the same as 'manufacture', literally speaking.

Answer (score 4):

The verb *make* has many quite varied senses, as consulting any dictionary will confirm. In this case it means catch, or arrive at in time to board and then in fact board. We speak of making a plane, making a train, making the bus, making one’s flight, etc.

This usage is quite similar to the sense of arrive, as in

- Did you **make it to** work in time for the meeting?
- She **made it** from the kitchen all the way upstairs without spilling a drop.
- I hope they can **make it** to the party Saturday.
- He struggled for years as a minor-league pitcher before finally **making it** to the big leagues.